# Passing array of custom type to postgres function from node-pg and SQL injection

Tags: arrays, node.js, postgresql, types, node-postgres

```
CREATE TYPE phototable AS (
    photoid integer,
    parentid integer,
    fileextension character varying(20),
    description text,
    tag character varying(100)
);

CREATE FUNCTION addphotos(
          p_placeid integer
        , p_permissiontypeid integer
        , p_description text DEFAULT NULL::text
        , p_photos phototable[] DEFAULT NULL::phototable[]) 

BEGIN
........
END
```

I am calling this function from node.js (using node-postres) by generating an SQL query. I want to avoid it and want to use parameterized queries because I think it is not secure against SQL injection attacks. I was not able to find a way to pass custom type array to the query method of node-postgres. Is there a way to pass custom type array to the query function of node-postgres?

Query:

```
select * from addphotos(p_placeid:=2210, p_permissiontypeid:=2, p_description:='Party', 
p_photos:=array[row(null, null,'.JPG','smart','6e8f74b2-4c14-4f40-ae19-8abae026a539'),
row(null, null,'.JPG',null,'c4e9f75f-25fa-4893-82f1-44c4791d58e5')]::phototable[]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with node.js, but you could provide a **string literal** for your column `p_photos` instead of the `ARRAY` and `ROW` constructors (which are functions that need to be executed at the Postgres side!). Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM addphotos(
    p_placeid := 2210
  , p_permissiontypeid := 2
  , p_description := 'Party'
  , p_photos:='{"(,,.JPG,smart,6e8f74b2-4c14-4f40-ae19-8abae026a539)"
               ,"(,,.JPG,,c4e9f75f-25fa-4893-82f1-44c4791d58e5)"}'::phototable[]
    );
```

Should even work without explicit cast:

```
SELECT * FROM addphotos(
    p_placeid := 2210
  , p_permissiontypeid := 2
  , p_description := 'Party'
  , p_photos:='{"(,,.JPG,smart,6e8f74b2-4c14-4f40-ae19-8abae026a539)"
               ,"(,,.JPG,,c4e9f75f-25fa-4893-82f1-44c4791d58e5)"}'
    );
```

The fast and simple way to "rewrite" your syntax to a string literal: let Postgres do it:

```
SELECT array[row(null, null,'.JPG','smart','6e8f74b2-4c14-4f40-ae19-8abae026a539'),
             row(null, null,'.JPG',null,'c4e9f75f-25fa-4893-82f1-44c4791d58e5')]::phototable[]
```

Returns the string representation I used above: