# Call a function with composite type as argument from native query in jpa

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, composite-types

I have created a postgres composite type and function as follows

```
CREATE TYPE  test AS (a int, b timestamp, c int);

CREATE FUNCTION some_updates(t test[])
    begin
    // iterate t and perform operation
    end

select some_updates(CAST(array[(488,'2019-7-01',342)] AS test[])
```

The above function and select to call the function works properly.

In spring jpa I would want to call function and pass values for "test[]" as params from native query. However it results in error.

```
@Query(value="select * from some_updates(:myinput)")
Myclass getDetails(List<test> myinput);
```

I have created a pojo class test as follows

```
class test
{
    int a;
    timestamp b;
    int c;

    //getters and setters
}
```

How can i possibly pass values to the postgres function?

Comment: You should consider to use jOOQ for this job: https://jooq.org

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "couldnt determine a type for the class" - the error.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an array *literal* instead of an array constructor. The value can be passed as [string literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS), then it is coerced to the right type by Postgres:

```
SELECT some_updates('{"(488, 2019-07-01 00:00:00,342)"}');
```

Precondition: the function is not "overloaded" so that function type resolution is unambiguous with untyped input.

Related:

- [How to pass custom type array to Postgres function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009822/how-to-pass-custom-type-array-to-postgres-function/17840058#17840058)
- [Passing array of custom type to postgres function from node-pg and SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384035/passing-array-of-custom-type-to-postgres-function-from-node-pg-and-sql-injection/20385037#20385037)
- [Is there a way to disable function overloading in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698641/is-there-a-way-to-disable-function-overloading-in-postgres/28710225#28710225)

If you have fewer than 100 array elements, a `VARIADIC` function would help to simplify passing arguments:

```
CREATE FUNCTION some_updates(VARIADIC t test[]) ...
```

Then pass row literals like:

```
SELECT some_updates('(488, 2019-07-01 00:00:00,342)'
                  , '(489, 2019-07-02 00:00:00,343)')
```

See:

- [Return rows matching elements of input array in plpgsql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978310/return-rows-matching-elements-of-input-array-in-plpgsql-function/17978831#17978831)

If you have (many) more rows to pass, consider writing them to a (temporary) table with a plain `INSERT` and processing them from there.

Comment: The function works perfectly when called within postgres sql. But I want to dynamically provide the parameters from java.Passing the request as string, i should manually code to convert the input to the above structure

Comment: @ManuKR: Not sure I understand the comment.